# structure padding for charcter

Tags: c, struct, padding

```
    struct struct_name {
                        char a;
                        char b;
                        char c;
     }
```

The size of the structure struct_name is 3 but

```
   struct struct_name1 {
   char a;
   char b;
   char c;
   int d;
   char e;
   char f;
   char g;
};
```

the size of struct_name1 is 12 why?
I know this is because of padding but why the size of structure stuct_name is 3 and why the sizeof structure struct_name1 is not 11.

Comment: Visit here [structure padding and structure packing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4306186/3293946)
you will find this post very helpful...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends on the plaform, but assuming a relatively normal environment with 32bit `int`s that need to be aligned on 32bit boundaries, you need that structure to be a multiple for 4 bytes in size. Otherwise, if you try to make an array of `struct_name1`, the `int` in the middle won't be aligned properly (there cannot be padding in between elements in an array).

If the compiler set that struct to 11, and array of two of these would look like:

```
abcXddddefgabcXddddefg  // X is padding
0   4   8   C  F        // hex offset
```

You see the first byte of the second `int d` is at offset 0x0F wich is 15 - not 4-byte aligned. So an extra char of padding is added:

```
abcXddddefgXabcXddddefgX  // X is padding
0   4   8   C   0   4     // hex offset
```

and the middle `int` will always have the correct alignment.